# C++ vector stack overflow in constructor

Tags: c++

I have the following code snippet:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct X {
    std::vector<X> v;
    X(std::vector<X> vec) : v{vec} {}
};

int main() {
    X{{}};
}
```

Compiling and running this snippet locally results in a stack overflow originating from `X`'s constructor. Inspection with `gdb` shows me that the constructor is somehow recursively calling itself, but that doesn't make sense because I'm not calling it recursively. Why might this be happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: X contains several (vector of) X? Is this a tree structure?

Comment: @Sebastian yes, it's a recursive tree structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has to do with how C++ chooses which constructor to execute. Notice that `X`'s constructor uses curly-brace syntax in the member initialization list, meaning that it's using list-initialization syntax. According to the [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#List-initialization):

> When an object of non-aggregate class type T is list-initialized, two-phase overload resolution takes place.
>
> - at phase 1, the candidate functions are all initializer-list constructors of T and the argument list for the purpose of overload resolution consists of a single initializer list argument
> - if overload resolution fails at phase 1, phase 2 is entered, where the candidate functions are all constructors of T and the argument list for the purpose of overload resolution consists of the individual elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list is empty and T has a default constructor, phase 1 is skipped.
>
> In copy-list-initialization, if phase 2 selects an explicit constructor, the initialization is ill-formed (as opposed to all over copy-initializations where explicit constructors are not even considered).

`std::vector` has an initializer-list constructor as noted [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), so this constructor is prioritized in the aforementioned phase 1. In the question, the non-explicit constructor for `X` means that the provided vector `vec` can be implicitly converted to an `X`, and so the vector constructor can be applied. Since this implicit conversion calls `X`'s constructor, you end up with the recursion described above.

To fix this, either [mark `X`'s constructor as `explicit`](https://godbolt.org/z/nqn4YhT5e), or [switch to `v(vec)` syntax in the constructor](https://godbolt.org/z/zo5oxTbbv).